# Correct usage of PaintTo in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a Firemonkey form in RAD studio and I am trying to do some experiments using MediaPlayer. MediaPlayerControl has a procedure named PaintTo, as the name implies I would expect by using this to be able and show my video in another object in my form. I don't know though, neither I can find in the documentation the correct way of using

```
MediaPlayerControl1.PaintTo();
```

It asks for a *TCanvas* a *rectangle* and a *FMXObject*. As a Canvas I tried giving

```
ImageViewer1.Bitmap.Canvas
```

but I don't know what an FMXObject is. Can someone provide a valid use of the PaintTo procedure?

Comment: What version of Delphi? I don't see the FMX TMediaPlayerControl.PaintTo anywhere in the documentation for XE7. A review of the source code in FMX.Media.Pas shows no mention of `PaintTo` except one boolean variable named `FInPaintTo`.

Comment: I am using XE6, and it definitely exists as it is one of the suggestions if I type Ctrl+Space after MediaPlayerControl.

Comment: That looks like it maybe comes from `FMX.TControl`, the ancestor of the media player control. I don't see anything in the MediaPlayerControl itself that implements it. `TFMXObject` is the base class for any Firemonkey component, which means that the `FMXObject` parameter would be any FMX component. (See the documentation for `TFmxObject`.)

Comment: I see, so PaintTo has not in reality anything to do with MediaPlayerControl.

Comment: No, PaintTo is indeed from `FMX.TControl`, documented (at least in XE7) under [FMX.Controls.TControl.PaintTo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.PaintTo).

Comment: PaintTo lets you paint a snapshot of the control to something else. It's not meant to be used to play your video in another form: to do that, put another instance of the media player in the other form, playing the same video.